# Laravel Custom Middleware: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, middleware, laravel-middleware

I'm using Laravel Breeze + Inertia (React) and want to implement custom auth.

I'm having infinite redirection (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS) when visiting `/dashboard` on this middleware.

```php
Route::get('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])
    ->name('register');

Route::post('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store']);

Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
    ->name('login');

Route::post('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store']);

Route::middleware(['custom_auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});

class CustomAuthMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session()->has('user_data')) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `RouteServiceProvider::HOME`?

Comment: it's dashboard. `public const HOME = '/dashboard';` . I believe you can also see on your laravel projects on this

Comment: which means you are redirecting to the same URL over and over again if the session has the data you are looking for ....

Comment: so what is the fix? post an answer and I will green check it if it works

Comment: not rediecting to the same route that you have the middleware applied on ... it is creating an endless loop of redirects to the same address ... this middleware isn't really useful (its not really doing anything in reality)

Comment: post a code. It will be better. I'm getting confused of this

Comment: So maybe something like `if(session()->has('user_data') && !Route::is('/dashboard'))`, or similar, or remove `Route::middleware(['custom_auth'])` from `Route::get('/dashboard', ...);`.

Comment: What's confusing? If you're currently on `/dashboard`, and your code triggers a redirect to `/dashboard`, what happens? You end up in an infinite loop of redirects, and your code is telling you that...

Comment: does it mean I can't let user access `/dashboard` or what? sorry I've been working on this for 1 more hour. get frustrated extremely

Comment: yea by letting the route pass through (`return $next($request);`) ... the other path should be redirecting to 'login' it would seem, no? ... either let them through to where they need to go as an authenticated user or redirect them to login?

Comment: In a typical Laravel authentication setup, you have a bunch of Routes that are "protected" by an Authentication middleware. If the User is not logged in, they cannot access those, and they will redirect to `/login` if not logged in. If they are logged in, and try to access `/login`, it will redirect them somewhere, like `/home`, `/`, or `/dashboard`, etc. Right now, you have it so that if you access `/dashboard`  with `session()->has('user_data')`, it redirects to `/dashboard`, which then redirects to `/dashboard`, and so on... You need to change that, using the other comments as guidance.

Comment: with all due respect, folks but just give me the working code. I can't see some enlightenment based on your explanations. you guys could use pastebin (or others)

Comment: The working code has been posted in the comments already... `if(session()->has('user_data') && !Route::is('/dashboard'))`, or remove `Route::middleware(['custom_auth'])` from your `Route::get('/dashboard', ...);`, so that the redirect to `/dashboard` **doesn't happen if you're currently on `/dashboard`**.

Comment: then it's not expected. I want the user to be redirected to /dashboard after they are logged in

Comment: Then add that middleware to your `/login` route, so that if they're on `/login`, and `session()->has('user_data')` is `true`, it'll redirect to `/dashboard`. And make sure that your `AuthenticatedSessionController`'s `store()` method does the redirect too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        if (session()->has('user_data')) {
            return redirect()->route('users.index');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class CustomAuthMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session()->has('user_data')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```

```php
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('register', [AuthController::class, 'register'])
        ->name('register');

    Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'registerPost']);

    Route::get('login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])
        ->name('login');

    Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'loginPost']);
});

Route::middleware('custom_auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () { return redirect()->route('users.index'); });

    Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
});
```